# C# - Require an environment variable in ConfigurationBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to require an environment variable to be set before running my ASP.NET Core server. I use `ConfigurationBuilder` to bind variables to a structure that lives in my object.

Here's a sample:

```
public class Config
{
    [ConfigurationKeyName("NOT_REQUIRED_VARIABLE")]
    public string? First { get; set; } = "first";

    [ConfigurationKeyName("REQUIRED_VARIABLE")]
    public string? Second { get; set; }

    public Config()
    {
        new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build()
            .Bind(this);
    }
}
```

In this sample, after calling `new Config()` without setting any environment variable, we will get an object that has `"first"` set in `First` field (not required to be set in environment) and a null string in `Second`.

Is there a way to set a variable to be required or not required specifically? It's gonna be a huge pain checking every non-required variable by hand in config creation or in business logic.

Comment: You should be able to add `[Required]` and then use the `ValidateOnStart()` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsbuilderextensions.validateonstart

Comment: @MartinCostello I believe `ValidateOnStart()` is used in ASP.NET MVC and has nothing to do with my configuration class. The question is mostly about implementing my own class to then pass its' instance down to the microservices and app business logic

Comment: It's not part of MVC, but the Options extensions, but your question did say "before running my ASP.NET Core server", so it's still a way to do what you want, just not within the specific class.

Comment: `IOptions<T>` instances are created lazily, I don't think there's any built in validation process that would run on startup. But, if an `IHostedService` fails to start, then the generic host will fail to start. So you could write your own service, register the service before the web server, validate configuration then throw an exception?

Comment: Ah, I see. `ValidateOnStart` is implemented in the generic host startup, after `IHostedServices` are created, but before they are started. see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7543b056d8ae0654f266b6298e8c14c0fb69f871/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L96

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing out of the box as far as I know. You can utilize `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` with it's attributes and `Validator`. For example `RequiredAtrribute` will check if property is set to not-null value:

```
public class Config
{
    [ConfigurationKeyName("NOT_REQUIRED_VARIABLE")]
    public string? First { get; set; } = "first";

    [ConfigurationKeyName("REQUIRED_VARIABLE")]
    [Required]
    public string? Second { get; set; }

    public Config()
    {
        new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build()
            .Bind(this);
        Validator.ValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this));
    }
}
```

Note that it has some quirks like handling value types (`Required` will result in check against `default` value for example).

Or you can use popular [`FluentValidation`](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/start.html) but basically with the same effect:

```
public class Config
{
    [ConfigurationKeyName("NOT_REQUIRED_VARIABLE")]
    public string? First { get; set; } = "first";

    [ConfigurationKeyName("REQUIRED_VARIABLE")]
    public string? Second { get; set; }

    public Config()
    {
        new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build()
            .Bind(this);
        new Validator().ValidateAndThrow(this);
    }
    
    public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Config>
    {
        public Validator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Second).NotEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that both of them will not actually check if environment variable was provided but only the bound value.

Answer (score 1):

Using `DataAnnotations` and `[Required]` attribute is a way to set a variable as required/not required.

From your comments - If you are required to implement your own Config class using `ConfiguraitonBuilder`, you would also implement your own validation. To validate your config properties in the posted code you could manually check for null of each property, use reflection, use a source generator, or there is a built in `Validator` class (which also uses reflection):

```
public class Config
{
    [ConfigurationKeyName("NOT_REQUIRED_VARIABLE")]
    public string? First { get; set; } = "first";
    
    [Required]
    [ConfigurationKeyName("REQUIRED_VARIABLE")]
    public string? Second { get; set; }

    public Config()
    {
        new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build()
            .Bind(this);

        Validator.ValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), true);
    }
}
```

If you're not required to implement your own config class, I would suggest to do what Martin Costello is saying in the comments, which would probably make you use Dependency Injection and options pattern instead of having `new Config()` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would like using below way to implement this requirement.

```
        // Bind and register the Config class
        builder.Services.Configure<Config>(builder.Configuration);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(resolver =>
        {
            var configOptions = resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<Config>>().Value;
            configOptions.Second = builder.Configuration["REQUIRED_VARIABLE"].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configOptions.Second))
            {
                configOptions.Second = "test mode";
            }
            return configOptions;
        });
```

Then we could achieve the variables like below in

*Program.cs.*

```
var config = app.Services.GetService<Config>();
config.Second......
```

*In Controller*

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly Config _config;

    public MyController(IOptions<Config> options)
    {
        _config = options.Value;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var requiredVariableValue = _config.Second;
        return View();
    }
// OR
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var requiredVariableValue = _configuration["REQUIRED_VARIABLE"];
        return View();
    }
}
```

*My appsettings.json*

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "REQUIRED_VARIABLE": "",
  "NOT_REQUIRED_VARIABLE": "first",
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: I believe this code directly checks `IsNullOrEmpty`. I want this process to be automatic.